# Problem in creating Ajax Menu

Tags: html, css, ajax

I am newbie to Designing, one of my friend suggests me stackoverflow community so here by i am posting my question.

I want to create a similar menu to the website given below for my practice

http://www.iwebsource.net/

Please suggest any resource,help which will solve my problem.

Regards,
Salma

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking out making these menus in CSS3, which is now capable of producing them more cleanly than AJAX. Here's a good tutorial: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-dropdown-menu

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. The skills required to create a menu like in your URL, comes after a very indepth study of various CSS concepts such as positioning, floats, box-model, to name a few. You would need to spend some time studying and experimenting with these. These are the ones, I found useful.

[A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/topics/code/css/)

[Max Design](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/css/)

[Menu Maker](http://purecssmenu.com/)